# How to Correlate desired properties of the Device to properties of the Capability Token when generating capability token from a web service

Tags: android, twilio, twilio-click-to-call

```
Uri.Builder b = Uri.parse(TOKEN_SERVICE_URL).buildUpon();
        if (newClientProfile.isAllowOutgoing()) {
            b.appendQueryParameter("allowOutgoing", newClientProfile.allowOutgoing ? "true" : "false");
        }
        if (newClientProfile.isAllowIncoming() && newClientProfile.getName() != null) {
            b.appendQueryParameter("client", newClientProfile.getName());
        }

        Ion.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(b.toString())
                .asString()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, String capabilityToken) {
```

I got the capability token from my web service, In twilio quickstart example they are using `TOKEN_SERVICE_URL` to generate a token. Now I don't know how to use this method to validate `clientProfile` with the capabilities inside the token. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You will be able to find the application server [here](https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-server-python). Basically it is a way for your application to authenticate with Twilio using a backend webserver instead of holding your API credentials.

Here's [an article](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/capability-tokens) that examplins how the capability tokens work, and will show you how to mudify the application linked in case you want to have fine grain control over the capabilities.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: What if i want to use the server for multiple clients, because of this i cant hard code the API credentials inside he python server. Thanks

Comment: In that case I would suggest having logic in your backend server to create the capability token depending on a key you passed from the app. So your app would pass something like "TOKEN_SERVICE_URL?cust=1", and then your backend server could go on the database and fetch key information from customer 1 and return an authorisation for that specific customer.